# MySQL command line import causes sql file to become empty

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I have a 8GB sql file called `test.sql`.

I am running this command to import it into my database called `test_db`.

```
mysql -u root -p test_db > test.sql
```

After a few minutes, the file `test.sql` is emptied so that it is 0KB.

I am unsure if this is normal and the file will be restored when the command is finished, or if something is wrong. It's been half an hour and I don't see any data imported yet.

Why is test.sql becoming emptied of it's contents when I run this MySQL import command?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.7.13.

Comment: `>` is export, `<` is import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong chevron. Should be the left chevron (`<`) not the right chevron (`>`).

This is what you meant:

```
mysql -u root -p test_db < test.sql
```

Comment: Hmm, going to try this right now. In the mean time, what is the `>` chevron that I was using intended to do?

Comment: `>` redirects output to a file, overwriting the file if it already exists.